# long long to int and int to long long conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion

I wonder if conversion like:

`int to long`

`int to long long`

`long to int`

`long long to int`

`long long to long`

`long to long long`

and

`long double to double`

`double to long double`

(and analogously for unsigned) are expensive operations. Should we worry about that conversion and define proper types for assignment? (Of course there is a risk of loss precision but I don't write about it. I'm asking about performance).

For example if I am sure that number can be store in `int` type. And I have to assign something in function like: `void writeToX(long long& x)`.

Is it important to pass to function `long long x` instead of `int x`?

Comment: You can't pass `int x;` to `void foo(long long&)` by the way.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Look at assembly or create a test program and see if it runs slower.

Comment: "Is it important to pass to function long long x instead of int x?" It's important to use the right size of variable.

Answer (score 5):

You should always strive to avoid type conversions, as they are normally indicative of poor programming style.

This is irrespective of the expense of a conversion operation, but do note that some of these conversions that you have listed - particularly to and from floating point to integral types - are not particularly cheap.

In C++, the behaviour on converting to a type that is not capable of holding the value is often undefined. So a *safe* conversion often needs to be implemented with size checking, which only adds to the expense.

Comment: "size checking, which only adds to the expense" - asserts are your friend, as you can get away with the expense being applied only to debug builds